# What is the best way to declare a bunch of drawables (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable, xml-drawable

I have a lot of vector icons as XML drawable resources (96 to be exact). I display them in 8 categories. Currently i declared them as follows:

```
private val categoryA = arrayListOf(R.drawable.a1, ... R.drawable.an)
private val categoryB = arrayListOf(R.drawable.b1, ... R.drawable.bn)
***
private val categoryH = arrayListOf(R.drawable.h1, ... R.drawable.hn)
```

Everything works fine and fast, but i am not sure if that is a good way for a real app. I also use Room DB for other purposes in the app, so should i add new table and prepopulate DB on first launch? 
It is also easy, at least right now, to add/remove icons later on... But on the other hand the code does not look nice (to me) with so many `R.drawable.id` lines.

Comment: Mmm I think it is not a good practice to store several drawables in your APK. You can use a server instead. In fact, there is not a good practice neither storing 96 static variables in runtime for your "production" app. Of course, this is my opinion, it doesn't have to be right.

Comment: Xml drawables will be small. Doesn't make sense to force the app to need Internet access to be able to run to temporarily save a tiny amount of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function that can get your drawable Ints by reflection:

```
fun getDrawableIdByName(name: String) = try {
    R.drawable::class.java.getField(name).getInt(null)
} catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
    error("No drawable with name $name")
}
```

Then you can construct your lists with it:

```
val categoryLists = ('a'..'h')
    .map { category ->
        List(12) { index ->
            getDrawableIdByName("$category${index + 1}")
        }
    }
```

I suppose you could write this to your database after the first launch, but I think it's overkill for only 96 items.

Comment: Writing to database would be an issue because resource IDs do not match between builds.

Comment: Yeah, you’d have to register a receiver for app updates and redo it each time there’s an update.

Comment: That´s an idea... I also found this guide today: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray . So would it be a better/worse way to create an array under res/values and define an array for each category there?

Comment: It’s a matter of opinion. I would probably do it this way rather than the xml arrays to reduce the chance of error. The xml arrays would be no better than what you originally had... a lot of typed-out values

Comment: i`ve tried this function, works very well for me, thanks. I have one "optional" question. Is there a way to get all drawables that start with "abc_"? Like getField.contains("abc_")

Comment: You can use `R.drawable::class.java.fields.filter { it.name.startsWith("abc_") }.map { getInt(null) }`